# Display left-bottom fixed popup on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, popup

I monetize my site through advertising.

I want to display a popup window. The window should be fixed in the left, bottom of the page.

The window should appear only after scrolling.

Here is the competitor page: http://teletarify.ru/tele2/tarify/moj-tele2
When the page is scrolled, a pop-up window appears in it. I uploaded a screenshot for better understanding.

Please tell me. How can this be implemented on jquery? My site on Wordpress. Or maybe someone will recommend a free good plugin for this?
[screen popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vQNq.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome. We are not intended as a code writing service nor for software recommendations but rather to help you with code you have written. Please take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: indeed "How can this be implemented [in] jQuery" is **too broad** a question; Ironically, you're also advertising your competitor here, which constitutes **spam**.  You could salvage this question by describing the desired behavior (as you have after the link to your competitor sentiment) and including a code snippet of your attempt to implement this feature.  It's also fairly likely it is a wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this css on popup
.popup{
 position:fixed;
left:0;
//you can adjust the value of bottom according to your needs
bottom:10%;
}
```

for dispaly pop up after scrolling use js onscroll funtion and set value in pxel and change style for popup to display:block;